# Convention for talking about instance/class methods in a module

Tags: ruby, oop

Given the following code:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def some_method
    end
    def self.another_method
    end
  end
end
```

If I wanted to talk to a rubyist about the instance method `some_method` I would say `Foo::Bar#some_method`.
If I wanted to talk about the class method `another_method` I would say `Foo::Bar::another_method`.

But what if `Bar` is a module:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    def some_method
    end
    def self.another_method
    end
  end
end
```

Is the convention the same?

Comment: Pretty sure it is, like if you look at [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html) source all the methods are prefixed with `#`

Comment: I would say: No.  The symbol `#` implies an instance method of a class, and  the `.` implies a method defined on the receiver, in this case a class method.  I believe the `#` just comes from ri.  I can't remember any notation to refer to some_method in the nested namespace Foo::Bar.  But you don't need any notation to describe it when talking to a rubyist.

Comment: technical syntax for documenting "class methods" is `Class::method` and "instance methods" is `Class#method`

Comment: @7stud: Just take a look the documentation http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html `#` is used everywhere : online documentation, ruby Method objects, irb, ri ...

Comment: @EricDuminilk, Good point.  I change my answer to Yes.

Comment: No one has to agree with me this is the way it is done Modules can have public "class methods" [Module Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html) please note `Module::constants` and `Module::nesting` vs all instance methods like `Module#include` BTW you reversed the order in my statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

The terminology is different though, a class has methods but for modules they are sometimes referred to as functions.

My source is the "Ruby in a Nutshell" book by Matz. He refers to methods defined on a module as module functions, thus also the name of the `Module.module_function` method. The same book has a chapter on builtin functions like `exit` etc, that are defined on `Kernel` module.

Fun fact, those "functions" seem globally available because `Object` includes `Kernel` and thus all its module functions become private methods of any object and are thus callable from any context. Expect `BasicObject` but that is another story for another time.

---

Or "Ask Ruby" as Eric suggested

```
[1] pry(main)> module B
[1] pry(main)*   def m
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)*   def self.n
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)*   module_function
[1] pry(main)*   def f
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> B.instance_method(:m)
=> #<UnboundMethod: B#m>
[3] pry(main)> B.method(:n)
=> #<Method: B.n>
[4] pry(main)> B.method(:f)
=> #<Method: B.f>
```

Three observations

- module functions are the same as "class methods" on a module
- "class methods" on a module are printed as `Module.fun`
- "instance methods" on a module are actually unbound.

Comment: Thank you for the quotes around "instance methods" since technically speaking all methods are instance methods because all objects are instances.

Comment: I'm not convinced. calling `include` to examine a method is supposed to be cheating, but `module_function` should be fine? `module_function` is basically like `extend self`, so you're just converting an instance method to a class method. Call them "functions" if you will, they're still all methods.

Comment: We can agree on Kernel methods being called functions, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil I cannot agree. These are instance methods of the `Kernel` Module and propagated through inheritance of the `Object` class' inclusion of this module. `BasicObject` does not include `Kernel` and has no access to any methods included therein. As a note to the answer this clearly indicates they are not "global". Ruby simply has keywords and methods that is all.

Comment: @engineersmnky: Thanks. I actually meant to say that Kernel methods are sometimes referred to as functions, because they look like functions from other languages ('puts/print/test/system'). Still, they are all methods, and it's never wrong to call them methods.

Comment: @akuhn:  As far as I can tell, the term "module function" isn't used often. Except in your answers :D."Ruby in a Nutshell" is 15 years old, by the way.

Comment: I knew that I'm old, but not that much, hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

When talking about that piece of code `Foo::Bar#some_method` would be called the *instance method `some_method`*. `Foo::Bar.another_method` would I call the *class method `another_method`*.

In the context of an module I would call `Foo::Bar.another_method` a *module method*. Whereas something like an instance method doesn't make sense in the context of a module. You might want to call that a function instead.

Comment: Actually `module_function` create "class methods" on modules, so that would make `Foo::Bar.another_method` a module function.

Comment: @akuhn,1) That isn't the only thing module_function does, so that is a bit of a mis characterization. 2) Dave Thomas uses the term [_module method_](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html) to describe a method that is defined inside a module and whose method name is preceded by the module name.

Comment: Talking about Module methods, `:instance_method` is defined as `Module#instance_method` and inherited by `Class`. So it looks like `instance_method` should make sense in the context of a module.

Comment: @7stud Ruby core seems to support the terminology of module method to refer to methods that may be called without an encapsulating, instantiatable object. This term is used in the documentation of Module itself

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the exact same convention, for the simple reasons that :

- [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Class.html) inherits from [`Module`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html).
- [`instance_methods`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) method is defined in [`Module`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html).